# Excel VBA crashes at 'Set ob = ORG.DrawingObjects(Array(arrObj)).Group'

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pretty large Excel VBA project that I have inherited that has just started to crash randomly. Sometimes, if I step through the code line by line (this takes 20 mins) then it seems to fix itself.

Just recently however the code is crash at this point:

```
Set ob = ORG.DrawingObjects(Array(arrObj)).Group
```

`arrObj` seems to hold 5 values and seems okay. I can't navigate to the `DrawingObjects` function at all though and can't find any reference on the Internet.

Excel just bombs out completely - I've tried to add error handling code and it never gets hit. I'm at a total loss.

The error log has this to say:

> Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 14.0.7015.1000, time stamp: 0x51cca83a
>   Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.22436, time stamp: 0x521eaab0
>   Exception code: 0xc0000374
>   Fault offset: 0x000c38b7
>   Faulting process id: 0x1edc
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d16a52e6d18209
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>   Report Id: f2948dc9-d646-11e5-8603-28d244b88aae

Comment: Hmm, faulting module name ntdll.dll  Sounds like it could be an unstable workstation/office install. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000960.htm  Have your tried another workstation or moving your code and data to a new workbook?

Comment: Yeah it's a total mystery. I'm trying to get it to run on someone elses machine at present. Given the fact it crashes at the same line each time though surely points to a run time error ? Incidentally I hate VBA and will make sure I never work with it again after this :-)

Comment: adding the following guard condition`If Val(CInt(Application.Version)) = Val(11) Then
                            Set ob = ORG.DrawingObjects(Array(arObj)).Group 'this is the line that crashes Excel 2010
                        Else
                            Set ob = ORG.Shapes.Range(arObj).Group
                        End If` seems to have fixed it for now - not sure why.